# remote script execution from local script linux doesn't stop for remote script prompts

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat, unix-shell

script abc.sh is on machine M1 and xyz.sh is on machine M2

script `abc.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -l user1 host.com ./xyz.sh -b1 arg1 -b2 arg2
```

script xyz has certain user prompts like pwd etc

When I execute script `bc.sh` from machine M1, it keeps looping with the `xyz.sh` script's user prompt on the terminal. It doesn't stop for user input.

Below is what I am trying to execute:

`./abc.sh -a1 arg1 -a2 arg2`

Answer (score 1):

ssh isn't allocating a tty. Add `-t` to the ssh command.

Comment: I had tried ssh -t option like below, same result. #!/bin/bash
ssh -t user1@host.com ./xyz.sh -b1 arg1 -b2 arg2

Comment: Does `-tt` fix it? Otherwise xyz.sh may be trying to detect if there is a tty in an odd way.